# IncrementKey of Parse api not incrementing

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a problem with incrementKey. I'd like to increment two keys of my user class, and they're not incrementing. Here's my code, if you want more details feel free to ask.

```
- (void) updateUserNbrQuestionsAnswered: (NSString*)FacebookID;

{

  NSLog(@"%@", FacebookID); 
  PFQuery *queryUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
  [queryUser whereKey:@"FacebookID" equalTo:FacebookID];

  PFObject *user = [queryUser getFirstObject];
  [user incrementKey:@"NbrQuestionsAnswered" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
  [user incrementKey:@"Points" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];

  [user save];

};
```

I call this function every time the user hits a button, which reload the view after incrementing on parse and updating a label. Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
PFQuery *queryUser = [PFUser query]
```

Change the save method with

```
PFObject* user;
...
..
.
NSError* anyErr = NULL;
[user save:&anyErr];
```

Ensure you have the write permission to alter the values of the User table (see ACL)